# Changing area units on Line Density Feature

Tags: arcmap

[image]

Why can't I change the area units on Line Density Feature? Is there any solution?

Comment: You need to read the help file! Especially the [syntax](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/line-density.htm) section.